# Implementing Horizontally Scrollable Date Picker in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I am trying to implement a horizontally scroll able date picker in angular 6 app just like this. How Can I ??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use NG2HzDatePicker with 6 version 
https://ahsanayaz.github.io/ng2-hz-datepicker-example/
after integrating you can overwrite its CSS according to your needs